# Can js-ctypes use gecko api?

Tags: firefox-addon, gecko, jsctypes

So with js-ctypes the way I have used it, is calling winapi. But I would like to use some mozilla functions. Is this possible?

Specifically I'm trying to use this one here: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/widget/windows/WinTaskbar.cpp#244

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `C++` stuff directly, exported or not, as js-ctypes only supports the plain `C` ABI. Unfortunately there is no common `C++` ABI anyway; each compiler uses it's own grant name mangling scheme and sometimes even `thiscall` calling convention...

However, if you really, really, really, wanted to get something working in mozilla-land, have a look at the [`glue` code](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/xpcom/glue/), which - in theory at least - could be used from js-ctypes (although I never seen it done).

In this particular case, `nwIWinTaskbar.defaultGroupId` [will return the verbatim result of `WinTaskbar::GetAppUserModelID`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/9305a8ec77fe/widget/windows/WinTaskbar.cpp#l323), so there is no need to go through js-ctypes in the first place.

Comment: Ah thanks man this was more out of curiosity then need. The `nsIWinTaskbar.defaultGroupId` doesn't get the group id of `firefox.exe` when i have the prefence to make profiles run separately set to true. And when this happens the pinned firefox.exe button sits there all alone forever, so I wanted to set default profile windows to use the group id of the pinned window.